# Replacement Character inserted between each letter of CSV Dataset. How to Replace?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, utf-8, special-characters, character-replacement

I'm working on importing a CSV dataset into a google sheet from my drive. I have the script working, however whenever the data imports it looks like this.

**After Import**
[image]

```
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(url);
  var csvString = file.getBlob().getDataAsString('UTF-8').replace(/\uFFFD/g, ''); 
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvString);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetid);
  var s = sheet.getSheetByName('Data');
  s.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

I've tried a number of different regex expressions to replace the unknown characters but after a few days trying to figure it out, I figured I'd post it on here and get a bit of help. (I didn't include the .replace() in the code because I couldn't get it to work. This is the code that is working to only paste it to my sheet)

Edit* Here is the Expected Output - I've whited out the email addresses and usernames to keep the information private.

**Expected Output**
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We need a bit more info to help you out. Can you please include some samples of the csv's text, as well as the expected output? If possible, please also include the file you're importing from - it's probably easier to import the CSV properly than it is to replace the bad characters. Finally, please include the `.replace()` function - we can't help you if we can't see the bad code!

Comment: My guess is that all those □ square characters are byte 0 values, because the BLOB contains UTF-16, not UTF-8, encoded text. Try changing to `getDataAsString('UTF-16')` to see if that helps. Don't know if you need `'UTF-16BE'` or `'UTF-16LE'`, but see if either of them works for you. My guess is `'UTF-16LE'`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Andreas! `'UTF-16LE'` worked. Thank you for the quick responses.